# etherjs equivalent of abi.encodeWithSignature

Tags: solidity, abi, ethers.js

I'm encoding parameters on-chain to pass into new OZ Beacon proxy instances.
For verification purposes, I need to encode the same arguments via `ethers.js`

The solidity function:

```
abi.encodeWithSignature(string memory signature, ...) returns (bytes memory)
```

And an ethers function that I tried, but returns an undesired result (longer, does not start with function selector)

```
  const abiCoder = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder;
  const encoded = abiCoder.encode(...
```

Answer (score 16):

This is how it is done as of ethers.js v5:

```js
let ABI = [signature];
let iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(ABI);
iface.encodeFunctionData(functionName, [param1, param2, ...]);
```

Note that `signature` needs to be in the format of `function functionName(type1 param1, type2 param2, ...)`.

[Also answered here in a GitHub issue](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/478#issuecomment-495814010).

Comment: how about with ethers js version 6? they changed quite a bit in the new version