# abi.encodeWithSignature but with ethers js V6

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I found this example code for how to execute `abi.encodeWithSignature(...)` but in ethers js instead of solidity:

```
let ABI = [signature];
let iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(ABI);
iface.encodeFunctionData(functionName, [param1, param2, ...]);
```

source: [etherjs equivalent of abi.encodeWithSignature](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/111343/etherjs-equivalent-of-abi-encodewithsignature)

However this is for versions prior to V6 of ethers. What's the new format for V6?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work.
Define interface object like this:

```
const ifaceERC20 = new ethers.Interface([
  "function approve(address spender, uint256 amount)",
  "function transfer(address to, uint256 amount)"
])
```

Then you can do something like the following:

```
tokenApproveCall = ifaceERC20.encodeFunctionData("approve", [SpenderContractAddress, 1000])
```

It does not change too much